# Is the absolute value of the difference between two Poisson distributions a Poisson distribution?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, skellam-distribution, absolute-value

What is the distribution of the absolute value of the Skellam distribution?

Comment: Very much related: [What is the expectation of the absolute value of the Skellam distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/279220/1352)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two quite different questions!

> Is the absolute value of the difference between two Poisson distributions a Poisson distribution?

This one is easily answered: clearly no, since the relationship between the mean and variance doesn't hold.

> what is the distribution of the absolute value of the Skellam distribution.

This second one is a little trickier. I'm working on a nicer way to do that than the <strike>brute force of stupidity</strike> *direct* methods. But since I don't seem to be clever today, here's one of the <strike>brute force of stupidity</strike> direct methods:

Let $Z = \max(X,Y) - \min(X,Y)$

\begin{eqnarray}
P(Z=0) &=& \sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X=i)P(Y=i)   \\
       &=& \sum_{i=0}^\infty [\exp(-\mu_1)\mu_1^i/i! \exp(-\mu_2)\mu_2^i/i!\\
       &=& \sum_{i=0}^\infty [\exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2))(\mu_1\mu_2)^i/(i!)^2\\
       &=& \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2)) \sum_{i=0}^\infty (\mu_1\mu_2)^i/(i!)^2\\
       &=& \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2)) \sum_{i=0}^\infty g^{2i}/(i!)^2\\
       &=& \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2)) \sum_{i=0}^\infty (2g/2)^{2i}/(i!)^2
\end{eqnarray}

where $g =\sqrt{\mu_1\mu_2}$

Now
$I_\alpha(x) =\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}$, where $I_\alpha(x)$ is a [modified Bessel function of
the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).

so

$$P(Z=0) = \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2)) I_0(2g)$$.

Now, for $j = 1,2,...$,

\begin{eqnarray}
P(Z=j) &=& \sum_{i=0}^\infty [P(X=i)P(Y=i+j) + P(X=i+j)P(Y=i)]   \\
       &=& \sum_{i=0}^\infty [\exp(-\mu_1)\mu_1^i/i!\exp(-\mu_2)\mu_2^{i+j}/(i+j)!\\
       & & \quad\quad +  \exp(-\mu_2)\mu_2^i/i! \exp(-\mu_1)\mu_1^{i+j}/(i+j)!]\\
       &=& \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2))\sum_{i=0}^\infty [g^{2i}(\mu_2^j + \mu_1^j)]/[i!(i+j)]!\\
       &=& \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2))(\mu_2^j + \mu_1^j)\sum_{i=0}^\infty g^{2i}/[i!(i+j)]!\\
       &=& \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2))(\mu_2^j + \mu_1^j)/g^j\sum_{i=0}^\infty g^{2i+j}/[i!(i+j)]!\\
       &=& \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2))(\mu_2^j + \mu_1^j)/g^j\sum_{i=0}^\infty (2g/2)^{2i+j}/[i!(i+j)]!\\
       &=& \exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2))(\mu_2^j + \mu_1^j)/g^j I_j(2g)
\end{eqnarray}

...assuming I didn't make errors - which I easily could have.

Another direct alternative would be to try to work with the Skellam distribution itself, but I don't think it's going to be any nicer.

---

Now, how do we check I didn't make a mistake?

I see a couple of approaches:

One check is to see if for some examples, the values sum to 1.

Another way is to compute a few values by direct summation, truncated when the terms become very small (the probabilities decrease quite rapidly) and compare with the above results.

Yet another is simulation.

(i) First, a function to compute the pmf:

```
 dabskel <- function(x,mu1,mu2) {
   g <- sqrt(mu1*mu2)
   emm <- exp(-(mu1+mu2))
   emm*besselI(2*g,x)*ifelse(x==0,1,(mu2^x + mu1^x)/g^x)
 }

> sum(dabskel(0:20,1,1))  # 20 should be plenty far enough to make it sum to 1
[1] 1
> sum(dabskel(0:20,3,2))
[1] 1
```

So it seems to sum to 1. Good start

(ii) Now compute directly:

```
x <- 0:8
y <- x
f <- function(x,y)dpois(x,3)*dpois(y,2)
probs <- outer(x,y,f)
f2 <- function(x,y)pmax(x,y)-pmin(x,y)
vals <- outer(x,y,f2)
asmres <- tapply(c(probs),c(vals),FUN=sum,simplify=TRUE)
```

(iii) Now simulate

```
 xyar=abs(rpois(100000,3)-rpois(100000,2))
```

And compare them:

```
plot(x,dabskel(x,3,2),type="h")
points(x+.04,asmres,col=2,type="h")
points(x+.08,table(xyar)[1:9]/100000,col=4,type="h")
```

[image: plot to compare algebraic answer, directly computed answer and simulated answer]

Black is the function worked out above, red is the direct-but-truncated calculation and the blue is the simulated distribution. Looks like it's okay.

Answer (score 6):

> OP:  what is the distribution of the absolute value of the Skellam distribution

Let $X$ ~ SkellamDistribution$(a,b)$, with pmf $f(x)$:

$$f(x) = e^{-a-b} \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{x/2} I_x\left(2 \sqrt{a b}\right)$$

Then, the pmf of $Y=|X|$ will be, say $g(y)$:

$$g(y) =  \begin{cases}f(0) & y = 0 \\ f(y) + f(-y) & y \ge 1 \end{cases}$$

All done.

Comment: You need to provide more explanation.  For example, what does $I_x()$ stand for?

Comment: No further explanation is needed: the solution does not depend on the functional form for $f(x)$. In fact, the mathematical description of the Skellam pmf is superfluous. I have left it in, as perhaps it adds completeness for those familiar with the Skellam, and detracts nothing for those not familiar with it.

Comment: @prob It is a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). I exhibit the (simple) derivation for $x=0$ at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49991/poisson-processes/49995#49995; it will proceed similarly for general $x$.

Comment: +1 for showing just how easy it is to do that way (much easier than what I did, though as expected, the final result doesn't yield any further simplification of the probability mass function).

Comment: I should mention, in case it's not obvious, that the expression I derived, and the expression above are the same (though I think the expression for the Skellam needs a $|x|$ for $x$ in $I_x()$). Note that $f(y)+f(-y)$ gives $e^{-a-b}I_y(2\sqrt{ab})\cdot\left((a/b)^{y/2}+(b/a)^{y/2}\right)$ and that $(a/b)^{y/2}+(b/a)^{y/2} = (a^y + b^y)/g^y$ where $g=\sqrt{ab}$. I think from there it should be clear to everyone that it's the same. Note that we don't need a $|y|$ for $I$ because $y$ is non-negative.