# What is the expectation of the absolute value of the Skellam distribution?

Tags: expected-value, skellam-distribution, absolute-value

In particular, for a Skellam distribution obtained by substracting two iid Poisson Processes. Thank you!

Comment: Taking $\lambda$ as the Poisson mean, I don't know how to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k I_{k}(2\lambda)$ -- at least I didn't see an immediate thing to try when looking at the double sum... and Wolfram Alpha didn't succeed with the sum even when fixing $\lambda$ (though cutting it off at finite values well above $\lambda$ yielded accurate numerical values). I wonder if you might get somewhere by looking at the joint distribution of the min and max of two independent Poisson($\lambda$) variates $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)})$ and then looking at $X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}$... ctd

Comment: ctd... though you'll probably end up with the exact same infinite sum to deal with I'd guess. For large $\lambda$ there's a normal approximation for the ordinary difference $X_2-X_1$ that would imply that the mean deviation goes to $\sqrt{\lambda/\pi}$. This works quite well, but it's a bit too large, roughly by a small multiple of $1/\sqrt{\lambda}$; it seems to be a useful bound.

Comment: Very much related (in spite of the title): [Is the absolute value of the difference between two Poisson distributions a Poisson distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/77705/1352)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the absolute value of the difference between two Poisson distributions a Poisson distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77705/is-the-absolute-value-of-the-difference-between-two-poisson-distributions-a-pois)

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to write the expectation in terms of easy-to-compute special functions.

Let $z$ follow a Skellam distribution with rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, and $k = |z|$. The pmf for $k$ is:
$$p(k; \lambda_1, \lambda_2) = \begin{cases} e^{-\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} \left( \left(\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\right)^{\frac{k}{2}} I_k(2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}) + \left(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right)^{\frac{k}{2}} I_{-k}(2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}) \right) &\text{if } k > 0\\
e^{-\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}I_0 (2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2})& \text{if } k = 0\end{cases}$$

Here $I_k(a)$ is a modified Bessel function of the first kind and has the symmetry property $I_{k}(a) = I_{-k}(a)$, so the moment generating function of $k$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{M}(t; \lambda_1, \lambda_2) = e^{-\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{tk} I_k(2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2})  \big[\big(\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\big)^{\frac{k}{2}} + \big(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\big)^{\frac{k}{2}} \big] - I_0 (2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}) \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Written in this form, recognize that the sum can be written in terms of a special function known as Marcum's $Q$ (used, for example, in the cdf of the noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution). A definition of $Q$ is:

$$ Q(\sqrt{2b},\sqrt{2a}) = e^{-a - b} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{\frac{k}{2}} I_k(2\sqrt{a b}) $$

So that the moment-generating function becomes:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{M}(t;\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = e^{-\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} \big(&Q(\sqrt{2\lambda_2e^{-t}},\sqrt{2\lambda_1e^t}) e^{\lambda_1e^t + \lambda_2e^{-t}} + \\
&Q(\sqrt{2\lambda_1e^{-t}},\sqrt{2\lambda_2e^t}) e^{\lambda_2e^t + \lambda_1e^{-t}} - \\ &I_0 (2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2})\big)
\end{aligned}$$

The derivative of $Q(\sqrt{2\lambda_1e^{-t}}, \sqrt{2\lambda_2e^t})$ w.r.t. $t$ is:

$$Q'(\sqrt{2\lambda_1e^{-t}}, \sqrt{2\lambda_2e^t}) = e^{ -\lambda_1 e^t - \lambda_2 e^{-t}} (\lambda_2e^{-t} I_0(2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 }) + 
\sqrt{\lambda_2 \lambda_1} I_1(2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 }) )$$

Differentiating the mgf around $t=0$ and simplifying **gives the expectation of** $k$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[k; \lambda_1, \lambda_2] = 2 &e^{-\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} \big( \lambda_2 I_0(2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 }) + 
\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2} I_1(2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 }) \big) + \\
&(\lambda_2 - \lambda_1)\left(1 - 2 Q(\sqrt{2\lambda_1}, \sqrt{2\lambda_2}) \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

The $Q$ function can be calculated using any statistical package that implements the noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution function (see below for an R example).

In the case where $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda$, **the expectation reduces to**:

$$
\mathbb{E}[k; \lambda] = 2\lambda e^{-2\lambda} \left( I_0(2\lambda) + 
I_1(2\lambda) \right)
$$

A numerical example in R:

```
set.seed(4) 
MarcumQ <- function(a, b) 
  1-pchisq( b^2, 2, a^2) 

# case where l1 \neq l2 
exp_k <- function(l1, l2) {
  a <- 2*sqrt(l1*l2)
  2*exp(-l1-l2)*(l2*besselI(a,0) + a/2*besselI(a,1)) +
       (l2-l1)*(1 - 2*MarcumQ(sqrt(2*l1),sqrt(2*l2)))
}

exp_k(5,20) # analytical 
# [1] 15.00187 

mean(abs(rpois(100000,5) - rpois(100000,20))) # simulated 
# [1] 15.0018 

# case where l1 = l2 
exp_k2 <- function(l) 
  exp(-2*l)*2*l*(besselI(2*l,0) + besselI(2*l,1)) 

exp_k2(20) # analytical 
# [1] 5.03042 

mean(abs(rpois(100000,20) - rpois(100000,20))) # simulated 
# [1] 5.03498
```